# Graph isomorphism of two graphs that have isomorphic subgraphs

Tags: graph-isomorphism, automorphism-group

Suppose we have two graphs that are isomorphic to each other ($G$ and $H$). We also have the bijection between the vertices of these two graphs. Now we add one edge to each graph ($G+e$, $H+e$). Is there any easy way to find whether the resulting graphs are still isomorphic or not? And also find the bejections among the nodes? I truly appreciate any help.

Comment: If you assume that you know the automorphism group of $G$ as well, then the methods of [Luks' paper](http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~luks/iso.pdf) can be used to solve some special cases of this problem.  I don't think that a general solution is known.

Comment: Is your bijection between the two graphs an isomorphism?  Or just any bijection between their sets of vertices?

Comment: Thanks @Qudit for the reply. I do not know the automorphism group of G in advance.

Comment: Thanks @avs for the reply. Yes the bijection is the isomorphism between two graphs.

Comment: I can check the isomorphism between graph (G+e) and (H+e). But knowing the fact that these new graphs both contains isomorphic subgraph can expedite the process of isomorphism checking or not?

Comment: You aren't going to be able to do this without knowing the automorphism group because the new edges could be attached to nodes that are not mapped to each other by the isomorphism you know but are mapped to each other by some other isomorphism.

Comment: I truly appreciate your response. I already know one isomorphism for G and H. Do you think there is a way to find all the isomorphism group based  on the only bijection that I know?

Comment: @Armita As avs mentioned, the problem of computing the automorphism group and the problem of computing an isomorphism are computationally equivalent. However, it's a Turing reduction and it works for computing isomorphisms for several variants of the original graph which are then used to find the full automorphism group. I doubt that there is any way to do it if you only know one isomorphism between the original graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we know every isomorphism $\phi$.

If the edge inserted into $G$ is $e = (v_{1}, v_{2})$, then check whether the edge inserted nto $H$ is $e' = (\phi(e_{1}), \phi(e_{2}))$.

This needs to be done for every isomoprhism $\phi$.  If the check fails for every isomorphism, then the graphs $(G + e, H + e')$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: The problem is I do not know every isomorphism. I only know one bijection between G and H. Is there any way I can find all the isomorphisms between G and H (isomorphism group) based on the only one that I already know?

Comment: This is the best I could find:

"The graph isomorphism problem is computationally equivalent to the problem of computing the automorphism group of a graph, and is weaker than the permutation group isomorphism problem and the permutation group intersection problem. For the latter two problems, Babai, Kantor & Luks (1983) obtained complexity bounds similar to that for graph isomorphism."

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem]